# Creating a for/in loop in an Angular 2 template

Tags: angular, typescript, for-in-loop

Is there a way to iterate over the properties of a static (Typescript) class, inside of an Angular 2 template? In other words, I want a for/in loop which iterates over an object instead of an array (so a normal *ngFor won't work). As far as I can tell, there is no directive in Angular 2 to do this, so I am wondering what the best way is?

For reasons to do with the module importing, the object must be brought in as a static class, and that data has to imported and then iterated over inside of another Angular component's template.

The static class looks like this:

```
class staticClassExample {
  static string1 = ""
  static string2 = ""
  static string3 = ""
}
```

And this is imported into an Angular 2 component:

```
import { staticClassExample } from './example';

@Component({
   template: '
 // LOOP NEEDS TO GO HERE
'})

export class Example {

  dataToIterateOver: any;

  constructor (private _myService: MYSERVICE) 
    {
       this.dataToIterateOver = staticClassExample;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, what about creating an empty array and pushing each property of that static class in that array for instance. arrEmpty.push(exambleObj.string1)

Comment: Are you able to return within a static function an array of pairs? [{k: string1, v: ""}...]

Comment: @lilezek I can't use methods inside the class, that's why it's static (it's never actually called or run).

Comment: @ashley I could use a regular for-in loop inside of the constructor I suppose, and extract out the data into an array. I just wondered if there was another way to do it, in the HTML specifically? But you're right, I should probably just do that, thank you!

Comment: @JazzyGreen, did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086340/2545680) help? You don't need an array to iterate an object properties

Comment: @Maximus I'm just trying it now. It doesn't appear to work, still getting the same ngFor error (iterating over an object). First time I've heard of Symbol.iterator though, looks cool, thanks!

Comment: can you maybe create a plunker? let's try to make it work, also can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @JazzyGreen, I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086340/2545680) with more details and the working plunker reference. Consider upvoting or accepting my answer if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ngFor` directive works with iterables. You can turn any object into an iterable by implementing `[Symbol.iterator]` method that will return an iterator used by `ngFor`. [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OaFYJftjEKPQs1W5o699?p=preview) that demonstrates that and the code:

```
class A {
  static a = 3;
  static b = 4;

  static [Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    yield ['a', this.a];
    yield ['b', this.b];
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let p of cls; let i = index;">
        <span>Property: {{p[0]}} and value: {{p[1]}}</span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  cls = A;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this won't work as it must work for static class, not for a instance of the class.

Comment: yeah, it will now, just added `static`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.dataToIterateOver = staticClassExample;
```

to

```
Object.keys(this.dataToIterateOver).map((k) => {key: k, value: this.dataToIterateOver[k]});
```

which offers to your template an array of pairs key, value, which you can iterate now with `ngFor`.